# How to use advanced Filter in normal Inquiries Forms in Ax 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

How to use Advanced filter for filtering Financial Dimensions in normal Inquiries forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Filtering on account and dimension in Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 and Microsoft Excel](http://arbelatech.com/filtering-account-dimension-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2012-microsoft-excel/) and [Dimension Provider Class and Run-time dimension ranges](https://sumitsaxfactor.wordpress.com/2011/12/16/dimension-provider-class-and-run-time-dimension-ranges-ax-2012/).

Basically you add a relation to the view `DimensionAttributeLevelValueView` from the base table containing the ledger dimension.

Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31177752/4509) may be of help.